# MacOS - inserting 'windows keyboard' disrupts apple magic keyboard

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, magic-keyboard-ipad

I have a MacBook Pro with the magic keyboard & mouse.

After plugging in one time a 'normal' windows keyboard, and then returning back to apple magic keyboard, some keyboard shortcuts refuse to work (such as F3, shift+down [yet shift+up works :D]).

I have tried doing 'restore' to the shortcuts, yet no success.

Any idea as for how to sort this issue out?

Regards :_)